# Rotating animation shown at final position only iOS swift

Tags: swift, animation, uiimageview, rotation

I am trying to implement custom activity indicator which is simple rotating UIImageView. I have next code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CatSpinnerAnimation: UIView {

let catImageView: UIImageView = {
    let catImageView = UIImageView()
    catImageView.image = UIImage(named: "CatDateIcon-1024")
    catImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return catImageView
}()

func startRotating(superView: UIView) {
    superView.addSubview(catImageView)
    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    catImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    catImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    catImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    catImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true



    let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
        self.catImageView.transform = rotate
    }

}



func stopRotating(superView: UIView) {
    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    catImageView.removeFromSuperview()

}
}
```

In my ViewControllers I instantiate an instance of this class and call its function

```
    let catSpinnerAnimation = CatSpinnerAnimation()
    catSpinnerAnimation.startRotating(superView: view)
```

But this doesn't show rotating animation at all, just my ImageView in final position (rotated for 189 degrees). I tried many types of animation but still don't have necessary result. I would appreciate any explanation of correct behavior of rotating animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to let the view be added to the view hierarchy first before you can animate it. Try wrapping your call to `UIView.animate()` in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .01) {}`

That would let your view be added to the view hierarchy and get rendered before you submit your animation.

Comment: You might also try a simpler approach of adding a small delay to your animation (Using one of the variants like `animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)` that includes a delay. I don't know if that would also solve your problem, but I'd be interested to know, and it would be simpler that the `asyncAfter` solution.